# including value from inner select statement to output

Tags: sql, subquery

I'm trying to check the total count(*) from the inner select statement

```
    SELECT *
     FROM CAR
     WHERE 4 <=   ( SELECT COUNT(*) 
                    FROM CAR_DRIVER
                    WHERE CAR.C_CARKEY = CAR_DRIVER.CD_CARKEY );
```

I tried `select count as total` but it doesn't work because the variable total is only valid inside the inner select statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `join` so you can fetch the value:

```
 SELECT c.*, cd.cnt
 FROM CAR c JOIN
      (SELECT cd.CD_CARKEY, COUNT(*) as cnt
       FROM CAR_DRIVER cd
       GROUP BY cd.CD_CARKEY
      ) cd
      ON c.C_CARKEY = cd.CD_CARKEY
 WHERE cnt >= 4;
```

Comment: didn't know it was that easy. Thanks Gordon